# How to disable dragging inside iframe element?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, drag

I'm trying to disable dragging inside my iframe element.

e.g. my iframe contains a map and I want to allow clicking on items depicted in the map but at the same time, I want to prevent the map from moving when dragged (thus disable dragging).

"draggable" attribute won't help as it prevents the iframe itself from being dragged.

I also tried to work with contentDocument and contentWindow properties of my iframe but with no luck.

e.g. the following code only works with a frame having an empty src="".
Once i define the src, the "click" event is never listened to.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="iFrame" width="800" height="600" src="...an embedded map source..."></iframe>
```

JS:

```
var win = iFrame.contentWindow;
var doc = iFrame.contentWindow.document;
win.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    console.log("iframe win clicked");
doc.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    console.log("iframe content clicked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cancelling the native event behavior?

```
var win = iFrame.contentWindow;
var doc = iFrame.contentWindow.document;
doc.addEventListener("drag", function(event){ event.preventDefault(); });
```